# Java Collection: Does concrete class HashSet which uses Hash table implemented using LinkedList as its data structure?

Tags: java, collections

In the book 'A Programmer's guide to Java SCJP certification by Khalid Mughal - 3rd ed.', on page 782, i noticed that it says that concrete class HashSet is implemented using hash table and linked list. When i browse through the main java tutorial website http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/index.html, it doesn't seem to be true. Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to see how the standard collection classes are implemented, look up the source code in `src.zip`, which you can find in your JDK installation directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HashSet` is a wrapper for `HashMap` which in turn use an array. `HashMap` is a hash table but not the `Hashtable` class. HashSet doesn't have anything to do with a list except to resolve collisions.

`LinkedHashSet` also has a linked list of its own, but does not use the `LinkedList` class.

Comment: Seems people get confused with "hash table", the concept and Hashtable, an implementation. And I guess a HashSet would also use a linked list internally, for instance for the bucket of objects with the same hashcode.

Comment: Check out the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/HashSet.java#HashSet) for Oracle's implementation of `HashSet` which nicely shows the `HashMap` used internally.

Comment: Ustaman and Peter Lawrey statements kind of contradicting. One says it has nothing to do with list and the other says otherwise.

Comment: It worth noting that while there is generally good reason to implement classes differently to the Oracle/OpenJDK version, if its not specified in the documentation it could be different, or it could be changed in the future.

Comment: We both say that a "list" is used to handle collisions (objects with the same bucket based on hashcode), in the general meaning of the word list.  This doesn't mean that a `List` or `LinkedList` class is used. It is possible to implement a hash table without such a list (which I how I prefer to implement it ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to code of HashSet,

```
public HashSet() {
    map = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Hash table based implementation of the Map interface. This implementation provides all of the optional map operations, and permits null values and the null key.  (The HashMap class is roughly equivalent to Hashtable, except that it is unsynchronized and permits nulls.) This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map, in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.